# Pixelly distortion when up close to volumetric clouds

Tags: unity, hdrp, clouds

I just getting started dabbling with game development and Unity. I'm creating a flying game, and so far have a player-controlled character set up. Next I'm working on clouds. I've set up Unity's [HDRP](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@14.0/manual/index.html) and added their [Volumetric Clouds](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@14.0/manual/Override-Volumetric-Clouds.html). They look very nice at a distance, but something strange happens when I get close. I'm not quite sure how to describe it, other than the edges and other thin bits get sort of fuzzy, or pixel-y, or particle-y. I've attached an animated clip to show you what I mean.

[image: pixel-y clouds]
(That's not distortion from the gif compression, that's how it actually looks.)

Sometimes, these pixel-y areas of the clouds seem to interact with the lighting to produce these unnatural (though admittedly very nice looking) streaks:

[image: Streaks in the clouds]

I'm not even sure what to call these phenomena, let alone how to fix them. Any advice on what settings to tweak or where to look for help is appreciated.

Comment: This rendering technique will likely not be appropriate for your use case, and you may need to explore completely different alternative ways to draw your clouds - there might be no settings that eliminate these artifacts completely. (If there were, the asset would probably just ship that way)

Comment: @DMGregory Looks like I was able to eliminate nearly all of these problems by jacking up the "Num Primary Steps" quality parameter to 650. The fuzziness shown in the first image is gone, and the phenomena shown in the second happens only very rarely. Of course, the downside is that it *eats* my GPU.

Comment: If that solved your problem, be sure to post it in the "Your Answer" box below.